# Анимация закрытия приложения

Tags: android

У меня в приложении стоит тема с параметром `windowIsTranslucent = true`. Из-за этого при закрытии приложения не срабатывает стандартная анимация. Сам параметр убрать не могу. Возможно, есть какой-то обход данной проблемы?